# Dockerize React + Redux app running Node server & Webpack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, webpack

The following is my project structure.

```
root
├── public
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   └── index.html
├── server
│   └── index.js
├── src
    └── index.js
```

It's a React + Redux web application with a Node.js Express server to server the routes. Webpack build everything into the /dist folder.

I have created the following Dockerfile, tried building and running but it doesn't work.

```
FROM node:8.11.3

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app/
RUN npm install

CMD npm run build && npm start

EXPOSE 8080
```

What's the right production grade Dockerfile configuration that I would use?

UPDATE: This is the error I get.

```
# docker run -i -t -p 8080:8080 45e219dfed94

> myapp@1.0.0 build /app
> webpack --mode production

sh: 1: webpack: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! myapp@1.0.0 build: `webpack --mode production`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-08-15T12_15_41_041Z-debug.log
```

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" can you be more specific. Also it would make more sense to have your React frontend and the express backend be in 2 different containers. You can use `docker-compose` to run both of the containers at once then if you need to

Comment: Added the error I get. I fails to find webpack.

Comment: Also the image contains only `node_modules` and `package.json`. `node_modules` doesn't contain webpack.

Comment: `webpack` won't be installed globally in that container image. You would need to have it as a dependency and set it up in the `scripts` section of you `package.json`. That way you can do `npm run ...` inside your container. It seems like you're trying to do too many things at once that you aren't fully read up on yet, I would take it a step at a time and learn how webpack builds work, split up your frontend and backend, and follow some Docker tutorials on how to create images properly

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

A 'webpack not found' error is indicative of webpack not being installed inside the container. Add the following to your project's package.json inside of "dependencies":

```
  "webpack": "^4.0.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
```

So that it looks like this

```
"dependencies": {
  ...,
  "webpack": "^4.0.1",
  "webpack-cli": "^2.0.9"
},
```

Comment: They are part of `devDependencies`. Is that the problem? Also the image contains only `node_modules` and `package.json `. I cannot see any other folders and files in there. :(

Comment: Yes, if you set NODE_ENV and webpack is only a dev dependency, an npm install won’t install webpack since it’s not a “dev” environment

Comment: Webpack should be in `devDependencies`, it's a dev tool and is only required for building your app, not running it